# GoogleAppScript - How to auto tick checkbox in a particular sheet row when the details from that row is used to make a google calendar events?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a particular function which creates a calendar event for the details stored in each row of a particular google sheet. The issue is that I need to make the checkbox go from unticked to ticked when the entry has been made using the info on a particular row and also I need to add a conditional statement which check whether the checkbox is ticked before executing the part where the event creation happens. I'm currently making a python flask web app which uses the G-Sheet as a DB and this is one of the functionalities which I need to implement using app script.

This is the app script code I have written :

```
function addEvent() {
  let webinarCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("blablablablabla@gmail.com");
  let calendarSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let schedule = calendarSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0, 1)
  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
    webinarCalendar.createEvent(entry[3], entry[11], entry[12], {description: entry[10]});
  }
  );
}
```

I'm not familiar at all with javascript but I intend to start learning it soon. I was able to get this far just relying on the app script documentation, but this is where I hit the roadblock which my current skill level can't seem to address. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How exactly do you mean to make the changes on G-Sheet (add rows to the table, change content of the rows)? Manually or by external script?

Comment: In this case, every row of the sheet has cells , apart from the checkbox, with date, start time , end time, description used as the parameters for an app script function which generates calendar events. What I need is to edit the code I have made to get the checkbox to tick itself after each row is iterated and calendar event created and also add a conditional statement which will check whether the box is ticked or not and will execute function for that row only if that box is unticked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addEvent() {
  let webinarCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("blablablablabla@gmail.com");
  let calendarSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let schedule = calendarSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0, 1);

  const k = 13; // colIndex of checkbok col
  const created = schedule.map(e => [e[k]]);
  schedule.forEach(function(entry, i) {
    if (entry[k] == true) { return; }
    webinarCalendar.createEvent(entry[3], entry[11], entry[12], {description: entry[10]});
    created[i][0] = true;
  });
  calendarSheet.getRange(2, k + 1, created.length, 1).setValues(created);
}
```

Reference:

[setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: I added the code you wrote into the existing one and I get this error. | Syntax error: SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement line: 9 file: Code.gs | . Line 9 here refers to if (entry[k] == true) { continue; }. Also the execution log said : Attempted to execute addEvent, but could not save.

Comment: try to change `if (entry[k] == true) { continue; }` by `if (entry[k] != true {`

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should be `return`. Have you changed `k` accordingly?

Comment: Just to clarify, Its 'return' instead of 'continue' right? I changed k to the proper column number by trying to start the column count from 0 as well as 1. In both cases, the execution starts but ends with an exception. Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.
addEvent @ Code.gs:14

Comment: Yes, `return` should be used for `forEach`. `k` starts from `0`. I found another typo, it should be `[e[k]]`

Comment: Sir, the script worked :). but one glitch after it worked. the data on each row was iterated 4 times effectively duplicating the same event 4 times in the calendar and also the empty cell right below the last checkbox was ticked got a FALSE entry in text inside that cell. I'm attaching screenshots for reference. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TpYkEdEpCG4dIRW2YILw13HDZGFFJ2h9/view?usp=sharing     |       https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uYNEavsPjy9QQMlWt-_b2X15prOklk5F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I also tried running the code again after unticking the first checkbox. This time it only created one calendar event and it unticked the already ticked second checkbox right below it. and strangely the column header is being copied down into the first cell overwriting the check box for some reason. I will attach my current version of the code again for you to check.

Comment: Are you declaring `created` after `splice`? I have edited my answer as the complete code for easier understanding. I have no idea why it is creating 4 times.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H8hY-9wJ4UsiBA0LL91FfkvwD8L0lJGN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please arrange the sequence as I said. And the condition should be `if (entry[k] == true) { return; }`

Comment: fixing the position of splice solved it. Thank you so much Sir !

Comment: Sir there is one more issue I'm facing with the same script. I have added array formula function to 3 columns so as to automatically fill up when a new row of information is entered. Now when I try to execute the function after adjusting for the column number changes, I'm getting and error which reads : **Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.** . I added TO_TEXT function into the array formula and confirmed that the cells are string using the IS_TEXT function in another column but still getting same error

Comment: Please kindly create a new question and provide a copy of your sheet